# I'm attempting to write and read messages from a pipe through a parent and child function, but keep getting a "too few arguments" problem

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fork

So I'm attempting to write a program in Unix that allows me to use a pipe to write a message to parent function and read it from a child and vice versa. I was given code that allowed for me to successfully write to parent and read from a child, but when trying to modify the code to allow for the reverse, I keep getting a "too few arguments" error for the child trying to write it's message. Specifically, I copied the function used to allow the parent to write to the child into the child process so that both functions close the "read" end of the pipe, write a message into the pipe as a passed-in variable, close the "write" end, read the message in the pipe, pass it to a read function, close the "read" end of the pipe, and then print whatever's been passed to the read function. It all makes sense to me as is, but its probably just because I'm failing to comprehend something simple.

First I tried adding a second message for the child to write to the pipe and a separate read function, but after thinking it through, a second read function didn't make sense since all it's doing is reading what's in the pipe, which will change depending on what has been written by the write function. I also tried having both the parent and the child just read the same message except the parent would print "parent: msg" while the child would print "child: msg", but that didn't solve the problem of "too few arguments" for the child function, which I don't understand since the arguments passed into the child function are the exact same as the ones for the parent save for the child being passed msg2 instead of msg, yet the parent works and the child does not. It's my understanding that the number of arguments passed into the function should be the same, but that's clearly wrong. Here's my code for clarification:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wait.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 40
#define READ_END 0
#define WRITE_END 1

int main(void)
{
   char write_msg[BUFFER_SIZE] = "People all over the world, join hands!";
   char write_msg2[BUFFER_SIZE] = "Start a Love Train (Love Train)!";
   char read_msg[BUFFER_SIZE];
   pid_t pid;
   int fd[2];

   if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Pipe failed");
        return 1;
   }

   pid = fork();

   if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed");
        return 1;
   }

   if (pid > 0) {
        close(fd[READ_END]);
        write(fd[WRITE_END], write_msg, strlen(write_msg)+1);

        close(fd[WRITE_END]);

        read(fd[READ_END], read_msg, BUFFER_SIZE);
        close(fd[READ_END]);

   printf("parent: %s\n",read_msg);
   wait(NULL);
   }
   else {
        close(fd[READ_END]);
        write(fd[WRITE_END], write_msg2, strlen(write_msg2)+1);
        close(fd[WRITE_END]);

        read(fd[READ_END], read_msg, BUFFER_SIZE);
        close(fd[READ_END]);

   printf("child: %s\n",read_msg);
   }

   return 0;
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand where nor how you are seeing "too few arguments." 
 In any case, the program as currently written does not compile.  Even if it did, both parent and child processes attempt to read from a descriptor each has already closed (EBADF).  However, one or the other or both might not get that far — writing to a pipe who's read end is closed (as it would be when both processes close `fd[READ_END]`) results in a fatal SIGPIPE.

Comment: You need two pipes if you want to communicate in both directions. You should handle the return value of all non-`void` functions. `read` and `write` tell you how many bytes have been read or written which can be less than the specified number. In this case you would have to `read` or `write` again to process the remaining bytes until you found a condition to stop (all written, expected amount read, special termination character found, error or EOF occurred, ...)

Comment: Thanks Bodo, that was basically my problem. I created a second pipe and fixed the code, works like a charm now!